# How to copy a NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring

I'm wondering how I can make a copy of an `NSMutableAttributedString`. I have a property called `text` that I'd like to save its contents at a certain point and revert back to it in case something happens. I've tried making a property called `textCopy` where I can save it to with `@property (nonatomic, copy)` but I get a runtime error when I do this:

> -[NSConcreteAttributedString insertAttributedString:atIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

How would I accomplish this?

I'm getting this anytime I set the `NSMutableAttributedString` to `@property (nonatomic, copy)`. I don't understanding why this wouldn't work. In general the copy parameter doesn't seem to work with `NSMutableAttributedString` whether I'm using its setter method or not.

Comment: Have you tried `NSAttributedString *temp= [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:[text mutableCopy]]; NSMutableAttributedString *textCopy= [temp mutableCopy];`?

Comment: What's the runtime error you got?

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer - I updated the question with the cerror.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you've declared the property with the `copy` attribute, and are presumably using the compiler-generated setter.  The compiler-generated setter sends the `copy` message to the object to make a copy.  The `copy` message makes an **immutable** copy.  That is, it creates an `NSAttributedString`, *not* an `NSMutableAttributedString`.

One way to fix this is to write your own setter that uses `mutableCopy`, like this if you're using ARC:

```
- (void)setTextCopy:(NSMutableAttributedString *)text {
    textCopy = [text mutableCopy];
}
```

or like this if you're using manual reference counting:

```
- (void)setTextCopy:(NSMutableAttributedString *)text {
    // Careful copy/release dance in case text and textCopy
    // are the same object.
    id old = textCopy;
    textCopy = [text mutableCopy];
    [old release];
}
```

Another fix would be to make `textCopy` be an `NSAttributedString` instead of an `NSMutableAttributedString`, and make the rest of your code work with it as an immutable object.

Comment: thanks Rob, on point like usual. Had another question: what if I just used @property(nonatomic, retain) for both, and when I want to make copy do something like this: NSMutableAttributedString *textCopyTemp = [text mutableCopy]; textCopy = textCopyTemp; [textCopyTemp release];

Comment: That middle statement needs to be `self.textCopy = textCopyTemp;` to avoid leaking the copy.